# .NET Core Facebook - "Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical"

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth, facebook-login

I'm out of ideas. I have a .NET Core 2.1 web app using Facebook Login. Facebook Login worked just fine until I upgraded from .NET Core 1.1 to 2.1. This works fine locally (localhost), but fails on our staging server (Apache on CentOS, EC2).

Our Facebook Login redirect URI is set up correctly in the Facebook app's login settings: `http://example.com/` and `https://example.com/` (see screenshot below).

What's interesting is in our .NET Core 1.1 branch, the request to `http://example.com/signin-facebook?code=SOME_CODE` shows up in the log once. In our .NET Core 2.1 branch, the request shows up *twice*, back-to-back.

Any idea how to dig more into the Facebook middleware that IdentifyFramework is using under the hood?

**Facebook Login Settings:**
[image: facebook app facebook login settings]

**Debug Log:**
.NET Core 2.1.802, CentOS (Linux), EC2 instance

```
// debug ouput

AuthenticationScheme: Facebook was challenged.
Executed action Foobar.Controllers.AccountController.FacebookLogin
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Request finished in 2.1144ms 302

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://example.com/signin-facebook?code=SOME_LONG_CODE

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://example.com/signin-facebook?code=SOME_LONG_CODE

Error from RemoteAuthentication: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: InternalServerError;
Headers: WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" 
"Error validating verification code. 
Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"
Error from RemoteAuthentication: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: InternalServerError;
Headers: WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" 

facebook-api-version: v2.12
```